# Why using @Transient Annotated will not create corresponding column...?

Tags: java, hibernate

**Why using @Transient Annotated will  not create corresponding column  in database tables...?**

```
@Transient
String getLengthInMeter() { }
```

if i am not using "@Transient" annotation then LengthInMeter  column will be created in database ,but if i using this annotation the corresponding column will not be created in database can any one explain why it will not created i am not Getting actual reason...

i studyed these links 
but still not understanding

Comment: Do you attempt to focus on how it is implemented? Otherwise, fields/properties marked by `@Transient` are not persisted - they are not persistent fields. It is documented and implemented that way.

Answer (score 0):

`@Transient` as the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Transient.html) explains, is meant for the fields that should not be persisted to the database.

Why? Because sometimes we have fields that we need in our class but not applicable in the database.

For example, `age` is something we need in a `Person` object but we don't need that to be persisted in the database. All we need is the `birthdate` to calculate `age`.

Another example is `fullName` which we might need for display purposes but we don't save that to the database simply because we just need to concatenate `firstName` and `lastName` everytime.

Answer (score 0):

@Transient - Is meant for property/field that are not to be persisted.

It means that the column value/field value will not be saved in the Database.

[JPA Transient](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Transient.html) - JavaDoc